# Animate "slides" on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, vs-web-site-project

I am creating a website that moves its "slides" when scrolling. I want to make it like that `http://www.highstudios.com` when scrolling down but dont know where to start or what to google.

but I have normal knowledge about css html and understand js a bit

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please describe your request in more detail.

Comment: I want my websites home to be divided into normal sections that seem to appear from beneath the above section (just like the example website) (http://www.highstudios.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can do most scroll-animations with CSS and HTML. I would check out these resources and see if they help. Possibly googling "css animated slides" might get you some more resources too.

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

and

https://css-tricks.com/aos-css-driven-scroll-animation-library/